# R: calculate average over a specific time window in a time series data frame

Tags: r

My dataset is a bit noisy at 1-min interval. So, I'd like to get an average value every hour from 25 min to 35 min to stand for that hour at 30 min.

For example, an average average at: 00:30 (average from 00:25 to 00:35), 01:30 (average from 01:25 to 01:35), 02:30 (average from 02:25 to 02:35), etc.

Can you good way to do this in R?

Here is my dataset:

```
  set.seed(1)
  DateTime <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010/1/1 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2010/1/5 00:00"), "min")
  value <- rnorm(n=length(DateTime), mean=100, sd=1)
  df <- data.frame(DateTime, value)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed the time interval of your example -  randomly simulating every minute of the year is not a minimal example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the existing answers are not general enough as they do not take into account that a time interval could fall within multiple midpoints.

I would instead use `shift` from the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

First set the interval argument based on the sequence you chose above. This calculates an average ten rows (minutes) around every row in your table:

```
df[, ave_val :=  
     Reduce('+',c(shift(value, 0:5L, type = "lag"),shift(value, 1:5L, type = "lead")))/11
   ]
```

Then generate the midpoints you want:

```
mids <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010/1/1 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2010/1/5 00:00"), by = 60*60) + 30*60 # every hour starting at 0:30
```

Then filter accordingly:

```
setkey(df,DateTime)
df[J(mids)]
```

Comment: I don't understand your critique. 1:25-1:35 is very disjoint from 2:25-2:35, right?

Comment: @Frank Totally agree - just wanted to point out that the existing solutions don't take into account another potential use case where you might have overlap.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, better, arguably, to have the intervals be symmetric around the relevant time as you do here.

Comment: This method is more flexiable and can be used for other purposes. Thanks Chris!!!

Comment: BTW, I can also use subset to extract the 30min in each hour after doing the moving average. For example, MA_30min <- subset(df, strftime(DateTime, "%M") %in% c('30'))

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(between(as.numeric(format(DateTime, "%M")), 25, 35)) %>% 
  group_by(hour=format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H")) %>%
  summarise(value=mean(value))
```

Comment: They want it for all 10 min intervals not just 25-35, i think

Comment: not familiar with `dplyr` but does this work if points fall into multiple intervals? I wouldnt think a filter - group by strategy could do this

Comment: Ah I see. Was too easy. :->

Comment: No problem, your interpretation would have been quite possible in my eyes, too. Thanks for undeleting, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to average on just a subset of each period, I think it makes sense to first subset the data.frame, then aggregate:

```
aggregate(
    value~cbind(time=strftime(DateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:30:00')),
    subset(df,{ m <- strftime(DateTime,'%M'); m>='25' & m<='35'; }),
    mean
);
##                   time     value
## 1  2010-01-01 00:30:00  99.82317
## 2  2010-01-01 01:30:00 100.58184
## 3  2010-01-01 02:30:00  99.54985
## 4  2010-01-01 03:30:00 100.47238
## 5  2010-01-01 04:30:00 100.05517
## 6  2010-01-01 05:30:00  99.96252
## 7  2010-01-01 06:30:00  99.79512
## 8  2010-01-01 07:30:00  99.06791
## 9  2010-01-01 08:30:00  99.58731
## 10 2010-01-01 09:30:00 100.27202
## 11 2010-01-01 10:30:00  99.60758
## 12 2010-01-01 11:30:00  99.92074
## 13 2010-01-01 12:30:00  99.65819
## 14 2010-01-01 13:30:00 100.04202
## 15 2010-01-01 14:30:00 100.04461
## 16 2010-01-01 15:30:00 100.11609
## 17 2010-01-01 16:30:00 100.08631
## 18 2010-01-01 17:30:00 100.41956
## 19 2010-01-01 18:30:00  99.98065
## 20 2010-01-01 19:30:00 100.07341
## 21 2010-01-01 20:30:00 100.20281
## 22 2010-01-01 21:30:00 100.86013
## 23 2010-01-01 22:30:00  99.68170
## 24 2010-01-01 23:30:00  99.68097
## 25 2010-01-02 00:30:00  99.58603
## 26 2010-01-02 01:30:00 100.10178
## 27 2010-01-02 02:30:00  99.78766
## 28 2010-01-02 03:30:00 100.02220
## 29 2010-01-02 04:30:00  99.83427
## 30 2010-01-02 05:30:00  99.74934
## 31 2010-01-02 06:30:00  99.99594
## 32 2010-01-02 07:30:00 100.08257
## 33 2010-01-02 08:30:00  99.47077
## 34 2010-01-02 09:30:00  99.81419
## 35 2010-01-02 10:30:00 100.13294
## 36 2010-01-02 11:30:00  99.78352
## 37 2010-01-02 12:30:00 100.04590
## 38 2010-01-02 13:30:00  99.91061
## 39 2010-01-02 14:30:00 100.61730
## 40 2010-01-02 15:30:00 100.18539
## 41 2010-01-02 16:30:00  99.45165
## 42 2010-01-02 17:30:00 100.09894
## 43 2010-01-02 18:30:00 100.04131
## 44 2010-01-02 19:30:00  99.58399
## 45 2010-01-02 20:30:00  99.75524
## 46 2010-01-02 21:30:00  99.94079
## 47 2010-01-02 22:30:00 100.26533
## 48 2010-01-02 23:30:00 100.35354
## 49 2010-01-03 00:30:00 100.31141
## 50 2010-01-03 01:30:00 100.10709
## 51 2010-01-03 02:30:00  99.41102
## 52 2010-01-03 03:30:00 100.07964
## 53 2010-01-03 04:30:00  99.88183
## 54 2010-01-03 05:30:00  99.91112
## 55 2010-01-03 06:30:00  99.71431
## 56 2010-01-03 07:30:00 100.48585
## 57 2010-01-03 08:30:00 100.35096
## 58 2010-01-03 09:30:00 100.00060
## 59 2010-01-03 10:30:00 100.03858
## 60 2010-01-03 11:30:00  99.95713
## 61 2010-01-03 12:30:00  99.18699
## 62 2010-01-03 13:30:00  99.49216
## 63 2010-01-03 14:30:00  99.37762
## 64 2010-01-03 15:30:00  99.68642
## 65 2010-01-03 16:30:00  99.84921
## 66 2010-01-03 17:30:00  99.84039
## 67 2010-01-03 18:30:00  99.90989
## 68 2010-01-03 19:30:00  99.95421
## 69 2010-01-03 20:30:00 100.01276
## 70 2010-01-03 21:30:00 100.14585
## 71 2010-01-03 22:30:00  99.54110
## 72 2010-01-03 23:30:00 100.02526
## 73 2010-01-04 00:30:00 100.04476
## 74 2010-01-04 01:30:00  99.61132
## 75 2010-01-04 02:30:00  99.94782
## 76 2010-01-04 03:30:00  99.44863
## 77 2010-01-04 04:30:00  99.91305
## 78 2010-01-04 05:30:00 100.25428
## 79 2010-01-04 06:30:00  99.86279
## 80 2010-01-04 07:30:00  99.63516
## 81 2010-01-04 08:30:00  99.65747
## 82 2010-01-04 09:30:00  99.57810
## 83 2010-01-04 10:30:00  99.77603
## 84 2010-01-04 11:30:00  99.85140
## 85 2010-01-04 12:30:00 100.82995
## 86 2010-01-04 13:30:00 100.26138
## 87 2010-01-04 14:30:00 100.25851
## 88 2010-01-04 15:30:00  99.92685
## 89 2010-01-04 16:30:00 100.00825
## 90 2010-01-04 17:30:00 100.24437
## 91 2010-01-04 18:30:00  99.62711
## 92 2010-01-04 19:30:00  99.93999
## 93 2010-01-04 20:30:00  99.82477
## 94 2010-01-04 21:30:00 100.15321
## 95 2010-01-04 22:30:00  99.88370
## 96 2010-01-04 23:30:00 100.06657
```

Comment: The 25-35 range was just an example, I think.

Comment: You could be right, in which case your use of `findInterval()` is more appropriate. We'll see what the OP says.

Comment: Oh, on rereading I think your interpretation is correct. Whoops, drove @lukeA to delete his answer.

Comment: @bgoldst I think this can lead to issues if points fall close to multiple midpoints